# Avoid multiple events on keyup, keydown when used simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code. If I press enter key, it triggers click twice. How to avoid multiple triggering of event?(Kepping keyup keydown together). Note: This situation is occuring in chrome not in IE

```
$(document).on('keyup keydown','#txtbox', function (event) {  if(event.which == 13 )$('#btnEnter').click(); return false;}});
```

Comment: Why you need to capture both events?

Comment: @ Claudio Redi I have written Textbox validation to restrict entering maxlength. My project has already this code. I cannot change it now. I need to figure out some way from existing code.

Comment: Where can you make changes then if not the posted code above?

Comment: If you are stuck with the code above, where will change the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got the most easiest solution. Use event.type property.

```
if(event.which == 13 && event.type == 'keyup')
{ 
 // Do some stuff. You can use event.type = 'keydown' also 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove one of the events:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function (event) { 
     if(event.which == 13 ) $('#btnEnter').click();
});
```

Every keypress (now, that's another event by the way), triggers both `keydown` and `keyup` events, doesn't it?

Comment: As I already mentioned in question I have to figure out way from existing code

Comment: What does `$('#btnEnter').click();` do? And by the way, you mean you CANNOT EDIT THE CODE? You need to explain some more, why you have to keep both events.

Comment: Well then (I still don't fully understand), if you try Aramil's code, it should work. Have you?

Comment: No, It doesn't, as you have to make triggered = false and by the time trigger event will trigger again

Answer (score 0):

This is what I quickly came up with. Is this what you're after?

```js
$(document).on('keyup keydown', function (event) {
    if(event.which === 13 ) {
        $('#btnEnter').click();
    }
});

$('#btnEnter').click(function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass("keydown") ) {
        return;
    }
    $("div").append("I'm clicked on keydown only!<br/>");
    $(this).is(".keydown") || $(this).addClass("keydown");

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#btnEnter').removeClass("keydown");
    }, 150);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnEnter">I'd be clicked on enter key down</button>
<div></div>
```

**Edit:** To support my comment, you could do something like the following.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET", // Or POST
    url: "yourURL"
    //other settings
}).done(function(data) {
    //Do your stuff
    //And then, do:
    $('#btnEnter').removeClass("keydown");
});
```

Comment: So, in your ajax success/done function, do `$('#btnEnter').removeClass("keydown");`. `setTimeout` isn't required since you need to enable enter keydown as soon as ajax is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Extending this snippet, this works when the AJAX Calls are completed:

```js
$(document).on('keyup keydown', function (event) {
    if(event.which === 13 ) {
        $('#btnEnter').click();
    }
});

$('#btnEnter').click(function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass("keydown") ) {
        return;
    }
    $("div").append("I'm clicked on keydown only!<br/>");
    $(this).is(".keydown") || $(this).addClass("keydown");

    $.ajaxComplete(function() {
        $('#btnEnter').removeClass("keydown");
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnEnter">I'd be clicked on enter key down</button>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Create `var triggered = false;` and add

```
&& !triggered
```

To your if condition, and

```
triggered = true;
```

To your function and make it false again whenever your event is ready to be triggered again